# Angular testing stopPropagation via spyOn

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, karma-jasmine, event-propagation

I try to test my `stopPropagation` behavior. 
When i test it in my browser it works, the console prints only "button" and "between".

When i try the spyOn in the test, it doesnt work. 
It says that the method was called.

Here is a very simple example.

Angular Component:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-prevent-event',
  templateUrl: './prevent-event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prevent-event.component.scss']
})
export class PreventEventComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  clickDiv() {
    console.log("div");
  }

  clickButton() {
    console.log("button");
  }

  clickDivBetween(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("between");
  }
}
```

HMTL:

```
<div (click)="clickDiv()">
  <div (click)="clickDivBetween($event)">
    <button id="btn1" (click)="clickButton()">Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Test:

```
 it('should prevent the div click', () => {
    const spy1 = spyOn(component, "clickButton");
    const spy2 = spyOn(component, "clickDivBetween");
    const spy3 = spyOn(component, "clickDiv");
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#btn1")).nativeElement.click();
    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy3).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test should be :-

```
it('should prevent the div click', () => {
    const spy1 = spyOn(component, "clickButton");
    const spy3 = spyOn(component, "clickDiv");
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#btn1")).nativeElement.click();
    expect(spy3).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: thanks ... i spied (mocked) my stopPropagation method call *facepalm* time for a coffee :D ... thanks anyway... for the real case i use now `.and.callThrough()` because i want have the second spy and works now :)